# How to include page encoding to all the jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, utf-8, web.xml

I have included `<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>` in one jsp page and it displayed french characters properly.
But i want to include the page encoding to all the jsp pages.
In web.xml i included

```
<jsp-config>
      <jsp-property-group>
      <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
      </jsp-property-group>
 </jsp-config>
```

but it will work for tomcat7 i am using tomcat6.

Is there any other solution for this?

Comment: is your problem with values from your backend ? static html  content in your JSP ? parameters ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a meta tag instead of adding page encoding in all the jsp file or in web.xml . If you have a common .jsp file include

Comment: can u give me detail explanation?

Comment: <meta content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="Content-Type">

Comment: you can choose any charset which will be suitable.

Comment: thank u jessica but i have another problem with french character display. i have a file in which i should save french character i m using Fileinputstream and setting the charset but the french characters are displaying as "?" can u please help me...

Comment: which charset are you using?use a correct charset it will work.

Comment: problem is in windows system its displaying fine but in linux system its displaying as "?"

Answer (score 1):

You could define a new Filter in your web.xml and modify your answers there.

For example, you could put this in your web.xml :

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encoding</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.example.EncodingFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encoding</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*.jsp</url-pattern> 
    <!-- or any pattern you like to excluse non-jsp resources -->
</filter-mapping>
```

And create a `com.example.EncodingFilter` class like this :

```
public class EncodingFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter {

    // init, destroy, etc. implementation

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) 
            throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
        chain.doFilter(request, response); // pass request to next filter
    }
}
```

You could furthermore add tests around your `setCharacterEncoding()` call to filter only specific URI or exclude for example a non-HTML jsp or specific parameter, like a JSP outputing PDF if URL paramter `format=PDF` is provided :

```
if (!request.getQueryString().contains("format=PDF") {
        response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
}
chain.doFilter(request, response); // pass request to next filter
```

Comment: your answer is correct but if you could elaborate a bit it would be better.

Comment: @MaVRoSCy should be better now

Comment: Thank u preuk for ur reply but i m using only jsp and servlets,i am not using any framework...i cant use filter...

Comment: well, this is only from javax.servlet API ... as long as you have a web.xml it means you could use it ; i have this kind of filter working on pure jsp/servlet apps running tomcat6

Comment: i am getting "The type EncodingFilter must implement the inherited abstract method Filter.init(FilterConfig) " even after including the javax.servlet-api jar

Comment: that's what I meant with this line : `// init, destroy, etc. implementation` ; this is about implementing methods from an Interface, which a java language problem not related to servlet specificaly

Comment: in web.xml i am getting "The content of element type "web-app" must match "(icon?,display-name?,description?,distributable?,context-param*,servlet*,servlet-mapping*,session-config?,mime-
 mapping*,welcome-file-list?,error-page*,taglib*,resource-ref*,security-constraint*,login-config?,security-role*,env-entry*,ejb-ref*)"." when i placed filter tags at the bottom before the web app closing tag.. where should i add the filter tags??

Comment: i guess your web.xml is pretty old and its doctype is outdated. Could you edit your answer with you web.xml (at least web-app tag) ?

Comment: doctype is:<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.2//EN" "/web-app_2_2.dtd">

Comment: Are you REALLY running J2EE 1.2 ? if not you should consider upgrading your config file to match options offered by later J2EE versions ; as I understand you're french-speaking so take a look at [this french page](https://goferproject.wordpress.com/2010/10/04/en-tetes-web-xml/) or [this page](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/index.html) from Oracle

Answer (score 0):

If your parameters are not UTF-8 encoded when using Tomcat, try to adjust the Connector configuration in Tomcat's server.xml like this:
`<Connector port="8080" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
               maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
               enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
               connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true"
               URIEncoding="UTF-8"
   />`

Comment: that is  not going to do what the user is asking

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to apply encoding to all pages is using filter.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request,ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
            request.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
    //                response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
                    response.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);

        }

        public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
            String encodingParam = filterConfig.getInitParameter("encoding");
            if (encodingParam != null) {
                encoding = encodingParam;
            }
        }
```

Register this filter in web.xml